# Don't allow switching of closed posts to community wiki?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, closed-questions

I've noticed this behavior a few times recently, probably as a means of either avoiding further rep hits (from asking really bad questions) or to obscure who is asking inane questions.  I realize editing of closed posts is explicitly allowed on purpose, but can we freeze out this particular edit?

Comment: Just to allow for unlimited punishment? That's kind of harsh.

Comment: I don't really care that much one way or another... but I agree with Jon - your rationale seems a bit weak. If you really want to "punish" people asking bad questions, then flag them as offensive or spam...

Comment: @Shog9: Let's not go spam flag happy unless it really is spam. In fact, ditto offensive. I'm not saying don't flag -- flag when you should! But only flag appropriately. If something is blatantly offensive, flag it such. If it is truly spam, flag it such. But don't flag non-offensive, non-spam stuff just to penalize someone. (Even if he/she may actually deserve it.)

Comment: Noise is a problem, but there is no flag as noise except for comments. Perhaps there should be ... ?

Comment: AFAIK, Moderators do see and respond to offensive/spam flags. Of course, if *enough* people flag as spam/offensive, the post is automatically removed and the author penalized... Personally, I don't use either one much, but it's always an option (and an option for many users who lack the rep to just delete a question).

Comment: Doesn't need to be unlimited punishment -- stop counting downvotes when it's closed.  I think perhaps the problem is that sometimes closed posts are reopened, and (usually) closed posts are definitely staying closed.  Ones that are permanently closed IMO should be locked from edit.

Comment: @Joe: In the most egregious cases, diamond mods can already separately lock and/or close a post. Granted, this does not seem to be a power they take lightly, but they are capable of doing so. I think the idea of not counting DVs against rep once a question is closed is neat, but my pushback question to you: What happens if the question gets reopened? (And should we count upvotes during its closure?)

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is ... This just seems to add extra complexity for little real benefit.

Answer (score 5):

Totally against this. One, lack of wikification may be *why* the post was closed; there are cases where a post might get reopened upon being made wiki.

Two, for questions which are deservedly closed, and will remain closed, converting to wiki might be a "way out" for the poster to avoid taking potentially very harsh rep hits. I think that's very fair to the poster. If the question is closed and sitting at a negative score, the community is already informing them that the question is invalid for some reason; forcing them to take further rep hits is redundant at best.

Comment: "lack of wikification may be why the post was closed; there are cases where a post might get reopened upon being made wiki."  So this behavior is a tactic to support the wiki-police?

Comment: @Adam: i suspect this behavior exists because no one bothered to disable it. As the OP notes, all other edits are allowed on closed questions. Though it does still seem to be more likely that semi-NPR / NaRQ posts will get re-opened if they're marked CW...

Comment: NPR/NaRQ? Never thought I'd need to ask about an acronym around these parts ... but I do.

Comment: Initialisms/abbreviations. Acronyms you can say as words, well, NaRQ would be. NPR = National Public Radio. But in this context, Not Programming Related. NaRQ = Backstabber. But on SO, Not a Real Question.

Comment: Thank you. (Yes, I always use them interchangeably; I know that annoys some ... )